# What is the hard recursion limit for Linux, Mac and Windows?

Tags: python, recursion, platform

Python's `sys` module [provides a function](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) `setrecursionlimit` that lets you change Python's maximum recursion limit. The docs say:

> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent.

My question is: What is the highest possible limits for various platforms, under CPython? I would like to know the values for Linux, Mac and Windows.

**UPDATE:** Can we please avoid "You're doing it wrong" answers? I know that trying to do very deep recursion is usually a bad idea. I've considered the pros and cons in my specific situation and decided that I want to do it.

Comment: Doesn't that also depend on how much memory you have, etc.??

Comment: Likely equivalent to "what is the maximum possible setrlimit stack size on {os}". For Linux, I bet almost all of your userland RAM, but I don't know. Value can be manipulated with `resource.setrlimit`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061582/setting-stacksize-in-a-python-script

Answer (score 36):

On Windows (at least), `sys.setrecursionlimit` isn't the full story.  The hard limit is on a per-thread basis and you need to call `threading.stack_size` and create a new thread once you reach a certain limit. (I think 1MB, but not sure)  I've used this approach to increase it to a 64MB stack.

```
import sys
import threading

threading.stack_size(67108864) # 64MB stack
sys.setrecursionlimit(2 ** 20) # something real big
                               # you actually hit the 64MB limit first
                               # going by other answers, could just use 2**32-1

# only new threads get the redefined stack size
thread = threading.Thread(target=main)
thread.start()
```

I haven't tried to see what limits there might be on `threading.stack_size`, but feel free to try... that's where you need to look.

In summary, `sys.setrecursionlimit` is just a limit enforced by the interpreter itself.  `threading.stack_size` lets you manipulate the actual limit imposed by the OS.  If you hit the latter limit first, Python will just crash completely.

Comment: What should I put in place of 'target=main' if I don't have a 'main' object?

Comment: You put any function name there. It doesn't have to be called main.

Comment: Any value I put as stack size is not able to solve my recursion limit problem. I know that the real recursion depth I need is under 100k and I managed to run it under Linux, but not under Windows.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on Windows 10, Creators Update version. I can increase stack size this way up to 2^28-1 bytes (or 256 MB); not sure what the default is, but certainly much less than this. Why not more than 256MB? Perhaps some Windows limitation?

Comment: On macOS 10.14.5 there is the same problem and only this solution works! Thank you for saving my whole damn day!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't overuse recursive calls in CPython. It has not tail optimization, the function calls use a lot of memory and processing time. Those limits might not apply to other implementations, it's not in the blueprints.

In CPython, recursion is fine for traversing data structures (where a limit of 1000 should be enough for everybody) but not for algorithms. If I were to implement, say, graph related algorithms and hit the recursion limit, I would either implement my own stack and use iterations, or look for libraries implemented in C/C++/whatever before raising the limit by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it's more of an insightful comment than an answer. (And as an answer, it's of the "You're doing it wrong" type.)

Comment: Thanks @Xavier. fact is, in this profession, pretty much everything I learned from others was a shade of "you're doing it wrong".

Comment: I completely agree with you. You don't need recursion. You don't need stack limit. If you're causing Stack Overflow, you're doing it wrong. `=P`