# Calculate the extended gcd using a recursive function in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am given the function gcd, which is defined as follows:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if (0 == a % b):
        return b
    return gcd(b, a%b)
```

Now I am asked to write a recursive function `gcd2(a,b)` that returns a list of three numbers `(g, s, t)` where `g = gcd(a, b)` and `g = s*a + t*b`.

This means that you would enter two values `(a and b)` into the `gcd(a, b)` function. The value it returns equals `g` in the next function.

These same `a` and `b` values are then called into `gcd2(a, b)`. The recursive part is then used to find the values for s and t so that `g = s*a + t*b`.

I am not sure how to approach this because I can't really envision what the *"stopping-condition"* would be, or what exactly I'd be looping through recursively to actually find `s` and `t`. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why would the stopping case for the three-parameter recursive call be any different than the two-parameter recursive call?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense.  There will be infinitely many solutions for s and t.

Comment: You should probably read the question again, because there is nothing for us to do. Add some more info please!

Comment: @LoSauer: note that the homework tag is now [officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated); there is no longer a need to tag questions with it.

Comment: @DSM OK. I thought it might help search engines / meta-crawlers...

Comment: I added some more detail that hopefully makes my question more clear. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: @wim It does make sense, it doesn't matter which one you have. If you got one pair, you can then calculate all pairs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key insight is that we can work backwards, finding `s` and `t` for each `a` and `b` in the recursion. So say we have `a = 21` and `b = 15`. We need to work through each iteration, using several values -- `a`, `b`, `b % a`, *and* `c` where `a = c * b + a % b`. First, let's consider each step of the basic GCD algorithm:

```
21 = 1 * 15 + 6
15 = 2 * 6  + 3
6  = 2 * 3  + 0 -> end recursion
```

So our gcd (`g`) is 3. Once we have that, we determine `s` and `t` for 6 and 3. To do so, we begin with `g`, expressing it in terms of `(a, b, s, t = 3, 0, 1, -1)`:

```
3  = 1 * 3 + -1 * 0
```

Now we want to eliminate the 0 term. From the last line of the basic algorithm, we know that 0 = 6 - 2 * 3:

```
3 = 1 * 3 + -1 * (6 - 2 * 3)
```

Simplifying, we get

```
3 = 1 * 3 + -1 * 6 + 2 * 3
3 = 3 * 3 + -1 * 6
```

Now we swap the terms:

```
3 = -1 * 6 + 3 * 3
```

So we have `s == -1` and `t == 3` for `a = 6` and `b = 3`. So given those values of `a` and `b`, `gcd2` should return `(3, -1, 3)`.

Now we step back up through the recursion, and we want to eliminate the 3 term. From the next-to-last line of the basic algorithm, we know that 3 = 15 - 2 * 6. Simplifying and swapping again (slowly, so that you can see the steps clearly...):

```
3 = -1 * 6 + 3 * (15 - 2 * 6)
3 = -1 * 6 + 3 * 15 - 6 * 6
3 = -7 * 6 + 3 * 15
3 = 3 * 15 + -7 * 6
```

So for this level of recursion, we return `(3, 3, -7)`. Now we want to eliminate the 6 term.

```
3 = 3 * 15 + -7 * (21 - 1 * 15)
3 = 3 * 15 + 7 * 15 - 7 * 21
3 = 10 * 15 - 7 * 21
3 = -7 * 21 + 10 * 15
```

And voila, we have calculated `s` and `t` for 21 and 15.

So schematically, the recursive function will look like this:

```
def gcd2(a, b):
    if (0 == a % b):
        # calculate s and t
        return b, s, t
    else:
        g, s, t = gcd2(b, a % b)
        # calculate new_s and new_t
        return g, new_s, new_t
```

Note that for our purposes here, using a slightly different base case simplifies things:

```
def gcd2(a, b):
    if (0 == b):
        return a, 1, -1
    else:
        g, s, t = gcd2(b, a % b)
        # calculate new_s and new_t
        return g, new_s, new_t
```

Answer (score 1):

The base case (stopping condition) is:

```
if a%b == 0:
    # a = b*k for the integer k=a/b
    # rearranges to b = -1*a + (k+1)*b
    #             ( g =  s*a + t*b )
    return (b, -1, a/b+1) # (g, s, t)
```

However the exercise is to rewrite the recursive part:

```
g1, s1, t1 = gcd(b, a%b) # where g1 = s1*b + t1*(a%b)
g, s, t = ???            # where g = s*a + t*b
return (g, s, t)
```

*in terms of `g1`, `s1` and `t1`...* which boils down to rewriting `a%b` in terms of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

*"Write a recursive function in Python"*, at least in CPython, cries for this: be aware of http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit. This is, in my opinion, one of the most important answers to this question. Please do some research on this topic yourself. Also, this thread might be insightful: [Python: What is the hard recursion limit for Linux, Mac and Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917210/python-what-is-the-hard-recursion-limit-for-linux-mac-and-windows)

In conclusion, try to use an iterative instead of a recursive approach in Python whenever possible.

Comment: I would prefer an iterative approach, but unfortunately this is a homework assignment and a recursive method was specified.

Comment: Recursive is just fine as long as you're bounded, and I think GCD is `O(log(n))` at least. But still good to remember.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on Euclidian algorithm using better to while loop continued recursion even better and less execution

```
def gcd(m,n):
#assume m>= n
if m <n:
    (m,n) = (n,m)
if (m%n) == 0:
    return(n)
else:
    diff =m-n
    #diff >n ?Possible!
    return(gcd(max(n,diff),min(n,diff)))
```

it can be better by while loop

```
def gcd(m,n):
if m<n :
    (m,n) =(n,m)
while (m%n) !=0:
    diff =m-n
    (m,n) =(max(n,diff),min(n,diff))
return(n)
```