# Is there a way to make a recursion method with unlimited depth in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, infinite, depth

For example, when writing some algorithms on graphs like

```
def f(graph):
    #graph is dictionary of pairs vertex_i:{set of edges (i,j)} for 1<=i,j<=n
    def g(vertex):
        for vertex1 in graph:
            do sth
            ...
            for (i,j) in graph[vertex1]:
                ...
                g(j)#recursive call
        ...
        return ...

    return g(1)
```

limited depth of recursion is sometimes very annoying, because code becomes much longer and more complicated if you have to avoid recursion.
Is there a way to reach unlimited depth?
Maybe you can describe your *general* solution of the problem on the following method

```
def nthNumber(n):
    if n==1: return 1
    else: return nthNumber(n-1)+1
```

(I know it's simple stupid and please don't give answers like "You should have written just nthNumber(n): return n " - I'm intrested in general solution). Thanks for help!

Comment: Let me put in another way: is it possibly to make a recurison method with max. depth 10**4 or 10**5?

Comment: You can set the recursion limit to 10**4, but you may end up crashing python (it is probably over the safe limit - which is OS dependent). Also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917210/python-what-is-the-hard-recursion-limit-for-linux-mac-and-windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlimited recursion would require infinite resources; every function call requires a stack entry, and there is only a finite amount of memory to hold those. So, *no*, you cannot have unlimited recursion depth.

You *can* **raise** the limit, by calling [`sys.setrecursionlimit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit).

Comment: **Unlimited != Infinite**, What he was asking for is un'limited', meaning Python wouldn't enforce any limits on this.

Comment: @itsneo: that's just... splitting hairs. You can raise the limit to beyond what the OS or available hardware would allow. The point is that you'll run into *a* limit.